# Stored Procedures and Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework 5, and I reverse engineer code first the database I'm using, and then I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model so that I can use Stored Procedures as reverse engineer code first didn't provide the use of sprocs. Is this the only way to access sprocs?

Also, I realize that after the reverse engineer code first process is done a bunch of classes (tables from the database) are created but as soon as I add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, most of the classes go away. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

DbContext.Database property exposes useful methods
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.103).aspx

```
ExecuteSqlCommand( string, object[] )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.103).aspx

```
SqlQuery<TEntity>( string, object[] )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern that you can follow to create or support store procedures with the code first approach. here is a link that you can use to follow this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures

In few words you need to do the same that you do with model first, create a class that supports the inputs and a class that supports the result set.

And about the Data Entity Model and missing classes. You need to consider that you only can have one approach in a project: code first/(model first/database first), so this could be the reason why you are not seeing those clases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context.Database.SqlQuery to run SP.